# Intercepting call to closure in binding object in groovy script execution

Tags: binding, groovy, closures, metaclass

My goal is to execute groovy script with binding, where functions are predefined and interceptor log out execution time and result of closure evaluation. My sample code is:

```
  binding.login = { ->
     binding.event.appname=='login'
  }  def gse = new GroovyScriptEngine("src/main/resources/rules")
  gse.run('DSL.groovy', binding)
```

Inside my script I am making a call to login method. Everything works except I can't fugure out how to intercept it using MetaClass. My attempts like

```
  Binding.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String name, args ->
                       println ("Call to $name intercepted... ")
```

did not work. Later I figured out that closure is a property of the binding, not a method. 
Is there any way to perform interception in this scenario and how to do it? What would be a correct object for metaclass? As of note, my closure executed inside another nested closures. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you try the *getProperty*? http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+invokeMethod+and+getProperty

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the better solution, but i managed to do what you wanted by decorating the closures in the binding

```
binding = new Binding([
    login : { -> println "binding.login called" },
    echo : { String text -> println "test for $text" },
    foo : { a, b, c -> println "$a $b $c" }
])


binding.variables.each { key, value ->
    if (value instanceof Closure) 
    {
        binding.variables[key] = { Object[] args -> 
            long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis()

            value( *args )

            print "[$key method"
            print " args: $args "
            println " time: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - t0}]"
        }
    }
}


def gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(".")

gse.run('Bind.groovy', binding)
```

And this is my `Bind.groovy`:

```
println " ** executing bind"
login()
echo("echo")
foo("test", 4, "echo")
println " ** bind script done"
```

You could also try/catch a `MissingMethodException` if you didn't defined the method as a closure in the binding.

I also recommend you Laforge's slideshare in creating DSLs:

http://www.slideshare.net/glaforge/going-to-mars-with-groovy-domainspecific-languages

In this slideshare, Laforge shows binding using a class that extends script; i think that's a good approach. More OO.

**Update**

Take a look at mrhaki's suggestion to delegate method calls to a base Script class (also in Guillaume' slideshare):

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/groovy-goodness-create-our-own-script.html

I just used it to implement a DSL over JFugue and it worked right away.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have created nested structures in my DSL and

Comment: it was not working with your code, giving me MissingMethod exception. I did not figure out yet why. Guilliame's slideshare is very informative and use the same example as in Groovy for domain specific Languages book. Thanks for the links

Comment: Are you sure you didn't typed the method wrong? I mean, the examples i wrote worked here in groovy 2.0.1